# django celeryd using wrong broker even after config_from_object

Tags: python, django, celery

This is my celery file:

```
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.settings')
app = Celery('my_app', broker=settings.BROKER_URL)

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

and in my settings.py I have this:

```
#Celery stuff
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

But when running celeryd this happens:

```
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         default:0x1052af590 (.default.Loader)
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
```

It doesn't seem like it's using the configuration that I have provided. What am I missing?

EDIT: comment suggested me to use djcelery:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_HOST = 'localhost'
BROKER_PORT = 6379
BROKER_USER = 'guest'
BROKER_PASSWORD = 'guest'
BROKER_VHOST = '/'
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Even with this running celeryd still defaults to 5672

Comment: @kiran.koduru I just tried using django.conf instead and same problem :(

Comment: Why not use the [django-celery](http://celery.github.io/django-celery/getting-started/first-steps-with-django.html) package?

Comment: @kiran.koduru I just set it up and it's still defaulting to 5672

Comment: Can you update your code now that you are using django-celery?

Comment: @kiran.koduru just edited

Answer (score 0):

I  think you forget to specify `namespace` property in config_from_object method.

so, your need to replace this

`app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")`

with

`app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings")`